# Connection to DB works with next.config.js env vars but fails with .env file

Tags: javascript, mysql, next.js

I'm connecting to remote mysql DB from my next app with serverless-mysql library. To achieve that I'm using a SSH tunnel with ssh2 library.
The app is working right but I wanna take off the env vars from my next.conf.js file in order to push the code to a public repository and keep my secrets safe.
My next.config.js file now looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
      });

      config.node = {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    }
      return config;
    },

    webpackDevMiddleware: config => {
        return config
    },
    env: {
        SSH_PASS:'supersecretpassword',
        SSH_USER:'root',
        SSH_HOST: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
        MYSQL_HOST:'127.0.0.1',
        MYSQL_DATABASE:'databasename',
        MYSQL_USERNAME:'username',
        MYSQL_PASSWORD:'dbpassword',
        GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID:'xxxxxx',
        GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET:'xxxxxx',
        NEXTAUTH_URL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    }
  };
```

I created a file called .env in the root of the project and added the following content:

```
SSH_PASS="supersecretpassword"
SSH_USER="root"
SSH_HOST="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
MYSQL_HOST="127.0.0.1"
MYSQL_DATABASE="databasename"
MYSQL_USERNAME="username"
MYSQL_PASSWORD="dbpassword"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID="xxxxxx"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET="xxxxxx"
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/
```

And now application is throwing this error message when trying to query db

```
sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client'
```

I googled the error and tried some of the suggestions like ALTER USER and setting a new password. But I think that is not a problem with DB, because it works with exactly the same configuration. I put a console.log on the moment when app connects to db and checked that the configuration object that is provided to connect method is the same in both cases.

There is any difference between load env vars from .env file and loads them from next.config.js?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your entire `env` exactly the same?  My guress would be that since your env file is using double quotes, somewhere in there you have a `$` or some other "special" character that needs to be escaped.  E.g. `SSH_PASS="DgaH$a43"` will set `SSH_PASS` to `DgaH` + whatever the value of environment variable `a43` is, so you would instead need to do `SSH_PASS="DgaH\$a43"` (escape) or `SSH_PASS='DgaH$a43'` (single quotes)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dave. I tried to replace double quotes by single quotes in my .env and it still failing. And yes the content is exactly the same.

Comment: Finally I found a character different between the files that I did not detect after 1000 checking. Many thanks for your reply @dave. My app is working now :)

Answer (score 1):

I think since version 9.3 next.js creates, `.env.local` file and next automatically adds those variables to `process.env` but only on the server-side. In order to access env variables on browser, inside `next.config.js`

```
env: {
        SSH_PASS:process.env.SSH_PASS, // .SSH_PASS variable name in .env.local
        ....
        ....
        
    }
```

if you want to create your own .env file and then use this package:
[env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd)

But you have to inform next.js in your scripts:

```
 "dev": "env-cmd -f .env next dev"
```

Comment: There's no need for the extra setup in `next.config.js`, if you need an environment variable exposed to the browser just use the [`NEXT_PUBLIC_`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) prefix.

Comment: @juliomalves since I see that it is sent in next.config, i wanted to show how to customize in in next.config.js